# Angular 8: On Heroku subscribing to an observable returns HTML not json, but not when run locally

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, observable

### Summary

Receiving an `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse` error when trying to retrieve data from Mongo. The same exact code worked in Angular 7, and the Angular 8 code works find when run locally but not when deployed.

I verified the express.static directory, file structure, and package.json are set up correctly. Every other part of the app works fine - authetication, account creation, posting a new blog, editing an existing blog, etc.

Every page is displaying properly except one where I use .subscribe() to retrieve all blog posts. I have the exact code in a blog app built with Angular 7 and it works as expected. The main difference is I used Heroku's Mlab plugin to provision a db to host the data. The current code runs fine using Heroku local web however and when deployed I can still retrieve and display individual posts, login/out, create posts, create accounts, etc so data is flowing between Heroku and Mlab.

I added a button to retrieve a single document, and it loads as expected, but requesting all documents via subscribe is throwing an error. I've spent all day trying to figure this out to no avail.

---

### Code: Express/Node.js & Typescript/Angular 8

This is where static files are served from - tried both with
`__dirname` and without
Node.js:

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));

//  var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";   
//  app.use(express.static(distDir));
```

Here is the server side of the route:

```
router.route('/blog').get((req, res) =>{
    console.log('Blog route called');
    BlogPost.find((err, allPosts) => {  
        if(err){
            console.log('Error' + err);
            throw new Error('Unable to load blog posts');
        } else {
            console.log(" All posts data: " + allPosts);
            res.json(allPosts);
        } 
    });
```

BlogPost is a mongoose model and there have been no issues using it anywhere else.

Here is the code from the Service:

```
 //calls the server with a GET method
  getBlog(){
    console.log("Blog service")
    return this.http.get(`/blog`, {withCredentials: true}); 
  }
```

Here is the initial call from the component:

```
 getAllPosts(){
    console.log("Get All called");
    this.blogService
    .getBlog()    
    .subscribe((data: BlogPost) => {  
      this.allBlogPosts = data.reverse();
      console.log("Data Requested..."); 
    });
  }
```

---

### Results

Actual results: The app module loads, but the page is blank and an error is shown in the console.

The error is and HttpResponse error: `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad`

Part of the error message includes: `text: "<!doctype html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta charset="utf-8">↵  <title>Blog</title>↵  <base href="/">↵↵  <meta name="viewport" content="width=d ...`

This is from the index.html file. Does this mean that file is being returned instead of the Mlab documents?

The fact the exact same code works when an MLab db was provisioned using Heroku's addon makes me think this may not be something wrong with my code specifically, but I'm welcome to any suggestions. I may end up refactoring this, as I'd rather not use Heroku's addon if I don't have to (and I don't understand why that would make a difference anyhow)

### EDIT

It has something to do with how I have the routing set up in Angular or how Heroku handles it since it works locally.

Right now I have root redirecting to /blog which queries the server and sends every post to the frontend, which is causing the paring error.

I added a static landing page then link to a newly created blog/all route which queries for and sends all posts, and the data is delivered without the error.

Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you post json data from allPost

Comment: I tried console.logging it but I don't think it even gets to that point before the error is thrown. I even tried using just FindOne on the server to return a single document, but anything in the subscribe callback doesn't even execute.

I included some code in the original post that functions pretty much the same, but only pulls one record by it's ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to figure out a relatively simple solution, however I cannot exactly say why the code I posted worked locally but not on Heroku, but I do have a theory.

### Root Cause

The back end route serving the DB data was the same as the front end route serving the index.html. I suspect this did not matter when run locally because different ports were specified, but I do not know enough about how Heroku serves files to verify this is the case.

### Solution

Simply update the service and backend routes to differ from the app-routing module route.

In my case, the backend route was updated to `blog/all` and the http call on the Angular service was updated to match.

Service:

```
 //calls the server with a GET method
  getBlog(){
    console.log("Blog service")
    return this.http.get(`/blog/all`, {withCredentials: true}); 
  }
```

Server:

```
router.route('/blog/all').get((req, res) =>{
    console.log('Blog route called');
    BlogPost.find((err, allPosts) => {  
        if(err){
            console.log('Error' + err);
            throw new Error('Unable to load blog posts');
        } else {
            res.json(allPosts);
        } 
    });
```

App-Routing Module:

```
 { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your function in getting BlogPost

```
BlogPost.find({}, function(err, blogPost) {
   res.json(blogPost);
});
```

Comment: No luck, still getting the HttpErrorResponse. In other routes where I only retrieve one record using subscribe, it works fine. The only difference is I'm not saving the response to an array.

Comment: It has something to do with the way the angular routes are being handled on Heroku's end. 

I added a static landing page then linked to the page that showed every post and it works fine, but I end up with a JSON paring error if the landing page is removed and the dynamic page is the root page

Comment: also set your responseType to text from your service
return this.http.get(this.url, { responseType: "text"});